# ASP.NET Web API v.1 for .NET Framework 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Is there ASP.NET WebApi v.1? All info that I found was about ASP.NET WebApi v.2. But it is not compatible with Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4.

May be there are some alternative Web API Frameworks?

I have MVC 3 project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is WebAPI version 1. You can reference it using this command in the NuGet Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 4.0.30506
```